# Play framework, how to control session?

Tags: java, session, playframework-2.2

I'm developing web application with Play framework - Java and I have a problem and can't solve it. Please help.
Here is the problem. When user login to the application, application creates session variable and has to remove session variable in 10 minutes.
How do I control session timeout? 
Is it good idea that when application creates session variable, application also will create thread which run for 10 minutes. And then after thread stops, application will remove session variable.

If application creates a thread for every user, will it cause high load on server?

Comment: `Is it good idea ...` No, this is a bad idea. This will be against the rules of a RESTful Webservice. You need to store the time of the last user action in the session. If the time of the current time is larger then time of last action + timeout, then discard the session. [Play docu about sessions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaSessionFlash).

Comment: @Tom, what if user don't send request again,  how to know that time is out and discard session?

Comment: You could "ignore" that situation in the first step and maybe later implement a service, that removes old sessions every night.